# Как в форме Django CBV сохранить данные после POST запроса?

Tags: python, django

Не понимаю каким образом можно после POST запроса заново заполнить отправленную форму в Django 1.11. Во view.py следующий код:

```
class WhoisView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = "bgp_app/whois.html"
    form_class = forms.WhoisForm
    success_url = '.'
    req = {}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ret = super(WhoisView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.req["rqst"] = str(request.POST.get('query', ''))
        return ret

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(WhoisView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.req.get("rqst", None) != None:
            result = whois.single_request(self.req["rqst"])
            ret["result"] = result
            self.req["rqst"] = None
        return ret
```

Соответственно в `post` забираю с формы данные, а в `get_context_data` выполняю нужную функцию и передаю результат выполнения на страницу. После запроса форма полностью сбрасывается, чего хотелось бы избежать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного потупив таки сделал желаемое. Ниже код. Неуверен что это корректный способ

```
class WhoisView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = "bgp_app/whois.html"
    form_class = forms.WhoisForm
    success_url = '.'
    req = {}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.req["form"] = form
        return super(WhoisView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(WhoisView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.req.get("form", None) != None:
            query = self.req["form"].cleaned_data["query"]
            result = whois.single_request(query)
            ret["result"] = result
            ret["form"] = self.req["form"]
            self.req["form"] = None
        return ret
```